# How can I read in this semicolon separated data file in python/pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

how do I read in the following csv file (see structure below) with pandas such that each column holds the string separated by ';'. The resulting dataframe should be of size nx4 with strings as objects in each cell. Thank you in advance. What I have tried (and variations of) with no succes is

`df = pd.read_csv(path, engine = 'python', sep=';', dtype = 'str')`

[image: Data structure]

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The result is a nx1 Dataframe with df.iloc[0,0] = 'C;Y1;X1;K"characters"'. Basically the problem is that the delimiter does not seem to work.

Comment: The first line of the text file is throwing you off. Either take out ID or make it `ID;;;` Also, the K"Some string" is strange: Why the K preceding?

Comment: This would be easier to debug if instead of an image you post the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your input file. `read_csv` thinks there is only one column because you gave a single column header: `ID`.

Here is a modified `in.csv` file:

```
C;Y;X;Str
C;Y1;X1;"Some string"
C;Y1;X2;"Another. String"
C;Y2;X1;"maybe a different string"
```

And here is a full Python program:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('in.csv', sep=';', dtype='str')
print (df.head())
```

Finally, here is the output:

```
   C   Y   X                       Str
0  C  Y1  X1               Some string
1  C  Y1  X2           Another. String
2  C  Y2  X1  maybe a different string
```

--edit--

If you must keep the unusual K prefix for the strings, then here is another `in.csv`:

```
C;Y;X;Str
C;Y1;X1;K"Some string"
C;Y1;X2;K"Another. String"
C;Y2;X1;K"maybe a different string"
```

If you use skiprows=1 and header=None, then the call will look like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('in.csv', sep=';', dtype='str', skiprows=1, header=None)
print (df.head())
```

and the output will look like this:

```
   0   1   2                            3
0  C  Y1  X1               K"Some string"
1  C  Y1  X2           K"Another. String"
2  C  Y2  X1  K"maybe a different string"
```

Comment: I understand now that I need to use skiprows = 1, header = None, thank you. But I cannot just remove the 'K', that is probably the core of the issue, your solution will give me the same dataframe: df.iloc[0,0] = 'C;Y1;X1;K"characters"'

Comment: You don't have to use `skiprows=1, header=None` if you correct the header. And the solution works (see edit) so please try again.

Comment: thanks for your input, but the problem is that I don t get your expected output, which is the one I desire, the delimiter does not work for some reason and I get the output as stated above.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? (mine is 3.7.4). What version of Pandas are you using? (mine is 1.1.3).

Comment: I suggest you start with my in.csv and my program and see if you can reproduce my results.

Comment: I followed your suggestion, made new csv file in excel with your in.csv data, then read_csv in pandas and I get the 4x1 dataframe that has been bugging me, it does not delimit somehow. Python version 3.7.3 and pandas version 0.24.2.

Comment: I am not certain, that this is source of your problem, but you have an outdated version of pandas. Can you find a modern one, with the major /minor at 1.0 or higher?

Comment: Or if you must stay with 0.24.2 pandas, perhaps change all of the semicolons to commas in in.csv and take out the `delim=';'`